# Git inflate returned -3

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have a little problem with git. 
I have one big repo (30GB), and some way i cane clone this repo on another computer. 
Using my pc i can push,pull etc.
Someone?Something?
Will be grateful

git.exe clone --progress --branch develop -v "http://XXX

Cloning into 'XXX'...
warning: redirecting to XXX.git
POST git-upload-pack (225 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 2186, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2186/2186), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (276/276), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 10075324326: inflate returned -3
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: do you have enough disk space?

Comment: @ChrisMaes yes :)

Comment: It seems your git repo is corrupted. please run `git fsck --full` and send the output

Comment: $ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2213/2213), done.
 :))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Sounds like the remote server is sending you bad data, or you have an antivirus, proxy, or other MITM device tampering with the data.

Comment: Which git version are you using? Which remote hosting partner are you using (like github, gitlab, etc.)? Are you using a proxy? Do you have something inbetween here, *like* a proxy, that might be tampering with data?

Answer (score 0):

Something that helped me was [this very useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250524/git-clone-fatal/57253617#57253617).

Try the following:

1. Turn off Git compression:

   `git config --global core.compression 0`
2. Do a partial clone of the repository with `--depth 1` parameter, instead of a full clone. Replace `username@domain.com/path/to/git_repo/` with the actual path to the repository:

   `git clone --depth 1 ssh://username@domain.com/path/to/git_repo/`
3. Then try to get the rest of the repository:

   `git fetch --unshallow`
4. And finish it up with a regular pull:

   `git pull --all`