# git fetch pack has bad object at offset

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a git repo, but I suspect it may be too large. Therefore I've gone around and tried to clone with a workaround.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250524/git-clone-fatal) shallow method of cloning, which succeeded and downloaded the master branch.

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo link>
git fetch --unshallow
```

However, this version could not pull any remote branches, so I also added

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

After this, `git fetch` runs, but eventually errors out with.

```
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 29069 objects to send. (266 ms)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 3528485989: inflate returned 1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

How do I resolve this issue?